# How do I get ref to functional component through cloneelement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass a jsx element as prop and get a ref to the cloned element.

```
  interface IPropss {
        control?: JSX.Element
    }
    const Wrapper: React.FC<IPropss> = (props) => {
        const {
            control
        } = props;
        const ref = React.useRef()
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {control &&
                    React.cloneElement(
                        control,
                        {
                            ...props,
                            ref: ref
                        }
                    )
                }
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

This will not work. React tells that I need to use forwardRef, but how do I implement this?

Comment: forwardRef(clonedElement)